# I am struggling with expressing the second statement to FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

You have been put in charge of drawing up the schedule for a basketball league. The league involves
eight teams, each of which has to play each of the other seven teams exactly two times: one at
home and once away. Think of a reasonable language for this situation. Using your language,
express the following statements:

1. Two teams in the league have the same hometown.
2. No team plays two games on the same day.

For the first statement I did something like this, ∃x∃y(team(x)∧team(y)∧hometown(x) =hometown(y)). For the second statement, I am struggling to proceed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Is the first statement supposed to mean that there are exactly two teams with the same hometown?  Not three? Or two pairs?  If so, you'll need to add a good bit to your statement, since that only expresses that there are *at least* two teams with the same hometown.

(... this actually also makes me question whether FOL is really a 'reasonable language' for this problem ... especially if the goal is to come up with a schedule!  Some programming language make be better suited ....)

Also note that for your first statement to even express that there are at least two teams with the same hometown, you'll need that to assume in $team(x)$, you use $team$ as a predicate symbol, but in $hometown(x)$, you use $hometown$ as a function symbol.  Does your language maybe separate between these two kinds of symbols? Maybe predicates have to start with capital letters, and functions with a small letter? Something to look into ....

In fact, are you even allowed t use function symbols?  In many exercises of this kind, you are not. If so, you'll need to introduce a predicate/relation like $hometown(x,y)$ that states that $x$is the hometown of $y$.

For the second statement, maybe you could likewise use a relation ... how about $gameday(x,y,z)$, which expresses that team $x$ plays game $y$ on day $z$?

Good luck!!